# Whats the difference bw baggage and luggage

Tags: differences

Whats the difference between baggage and luggage 
Or is there any difference bw those?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U; you may be interested in *["Baggage" versus "luggage"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/baggage-versus-luggage)* I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] as an introduction to the site.

Comment: When you have luggage from a previous relationship, you can pack clothing into it. (More plainly, baggage is often used as a term for psychological encumbrances; I have never heard luggage used in this way.)